# How to index couchdb in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm trying to get the result sorted by the posting date for which i have defined an index

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": [{
            "PostingDate": "DESC"
        }]
    },
    "ddoc": "indexPostingDate",
    "name": "indexPostingDate",
    "type": "json"
}
```

Acc to the hyperledger fabric documentation i have to place this in META-INF/statedb/couchdb/indexes

With Sap hyperledger fabric platform i tried placing this folder both in vendor folder as well as directly under src folder.But none worked for me.

This is my code for querying result

```
queryString := fmt.Sprintf("{\"selector\":{\"id\":\"%s\"},\"sort\": [{\"PostingDate\": \"desc\"}],\"use_index\": \"indexPostingDate\"}",
        id)
    logger.Infof("Getting data for %s", id)
    oResultsIterator, responseMetaData, oFetchErr := stub.GetQueryResultWithPagination(queryString,
        pageSize, bookmark)
```

On invoking this function, i get this following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "GET_QUERY_RESULT failed: transaction ID: 9b7c42c09069855758ccdfbc30f5d75d38b51569a78e101584051e0fa142ebc3: error handling CouchDB request. Error:no_usable_index,  Status Code:400,  Reason:No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields.",
    "code": "CustomError",
    "status": 500
  }
}
```

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known limitation that you can't specify the sort direction in the Query with Fabric. If you need an ordered search, your index creation should specify the direction, so you can simply exclude it in your query.

Now that we support and recommend you use the official CouchDB:3.1, this may work, but I would need to test it.

You can simplify your query by the way by using backticks so you don't have to escape your quotes for ease of reading and writing: `` fmt.Sprintf(`{"selector":{"id":"%s"},"sort": [{"PostingDate": "desc"}],"use_index": "indexPostingDate"}`, id) ``

Comment: If is specify sort, it straight away gives this error GET_QUERY_RESULT failed: transaction ID: 9b7c42c09069855758ccdfbc30f5d75d38b51569a78e101584051e0fa142ebc3: error handling CouchDB request. Error:no_usable_index,  Status Code:400,  Reason:No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields.